# Sortable (alphabetically)

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list and I am sorting it

```
sortable: {
    mode: "single",
    allowUnsort: false,
    field: "LastName"
},
```

The thing is that when I click on the sort button the fields is been sorted alphabetically but first it shows the ones with the Capital letters and then the ones with the small letters (I am talking about the first letter).

Example:

- Administrator
- Doctor
- Programmer
- Scientist
- doctor
- pharmacist
- vet

What I want to do is this:

- Administrator
- Doctor
- doctor
- pharmacist
- Programmer
- Scientist
- vet

Here is my code

```
    var selectedUser = "";
    var selectedUserID = "";
    var selectedRole = "";
    var Rolesgrid = "";
    var Usersgrid = "";
    var gridRolesToBeAdded = "";
    var myIndex = 0;
    var str = "LastName";
    str.toLowerCase();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.location.hash = '#FormTitleHeading';
        $("#UsersMenu")[0].childNodes[0].style.visibility = "visible";
        $("#UsersMenu")[0].childNodes[1].style.visibility = "visible";
        $("#RolesMenu")[0].childNodes[0].style.visibility = "visible";
        $("#RolesMenu")[0].childNodes[1].style.visibility = "visible";
        $("#UsersMenu")[0].childNodes[0].title = "Add New User";
        $("#UsersMenu")[0].childNodes[1].title = "Delete Selected User";
        $("#RolesMenu")[0].childNodes[0].title = "Add Roles to User";
        $("#RolesMenu")[0].childNodes[1].title = "Delete Selected Role";
        Usersgrid = $("#grdUsers").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "application/jsonp",
                transport: {
                    read:
                            {
                                url: "http://" + servername + "/uBillingServices/Security/Security.svc/getUsers",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    LanguageID: 'en'
                                }
                            }
                },
                sort: { field: "LastName"},
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            UserID: { type: "string" },
                            UserName: { type: "string" },
                            FirstName: { type: "string" },
                            LastName: { type: "string" },
                            AvatarURL: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {
                row = e.sender.tbody.find(">tr:not(.k-grouping-row)").eq(myIndex);
                if (row.length == 0) {
                    e.sender.select(e.sender.tbody.find(">tr:first"));
                }
                else {
                    e.sender.select(row);
                }
            },
            change: function (arg) {
                var UserIDrow = this.select(),
                  selectedUserx = this.dataItem(UserIDrow).UserName;
                selectedUserID = this.dataItem(UserIDrow).UserID;
                selectedUser = selectedUserx;
                myIndex = this.select().index();
                $('#UserDetailsView').load('<%= Url.Action("EditUser","Administration") %>');

                //                      $.get( '<%= Url.Action("EditUser","Administration") %>', function(data) {
                //                      $('#UserDetailsView').empty();
                //                        $('#UserDetailsView').append(data);
                //                    });
                if (Rolesgrid == "") {
                    Rolesgrid = $("#gridRoles").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "application/jsonp",
                            transport: {
                                read:
                                                        {
                                                            url: "http://" + servername + "/uBillingServices/Security/Security.svc/getRoleMembership",
                                                            dataType: "json",
                                                            data: {
                                                                UserName: selectedUser,
                                                                LanguageID: 'en'
                                                            }
                                                        }
                            },
                            sort: { field: "RoleName", dir: "asc" },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        RoleID: { type: "string" },
                                        RoleName: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        change: function (arg) {
                            var selectedr = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
                                return $(item).text();
                            });
                            selectedRole = selectedr[0];
                        },
                        dataBound: function (e) {
                            e.sender.select(e.sender.tbody.find(">tr:first"));
                        },
                        selectable: "multiple",
                        pageable: false,
                        scrollable: true,
                        navigatable: true,
                        filterable: true,
                        sortable: {
                            mode: "single",
                            allowUnsort: false,
                            field: "LastName"
                        },
                        editable: false,

                        height: 160,
                        columns: [{
                            field: "RoleName",
                            title: "Assigned Roles",
                            headerAttributes: {
                                style: "font-size:small; text-align:center"
                            }, attributes: { style: "text-align:left" }
                        }]
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Rolesgrid.getKendoGrid().dataSource.transport.options.read.data.UserName = selectedUser;

                    var data = [{}];
                    Rolesgrid.getKendoGrid().dataSource.data(data)
                    Rolesgrid.getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
                }

            },
            selectable: "multiple",
            pageable: false,
            filterable: {
                field: "LastName"

            },
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: {
                field: "LastName",
                mode: "single",
                allowUnsort: false
            },
            editable: false,

            navigatable: true,
            height: 250,
            width: 100,
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowUsersTemplate").html()),
            columns: [{
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Users", attributes: { style: "text-align:right" }
            }]
        });
        var winNewUser = $("#NewUserWindow").kendoWindow({
            width: "480x",
            height: "450px",
            title: "Add New User",
            content: "/Administration/AddNewUser",
            actions: ["Close"],
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            visible: false,
            shadow: false
        }).data("kendoWindow");


        //             var winEditUser = $("#EditUserWindow").kendoWindow({
        //                    width: "480x",
        //                        height: "450px",
        //                        title: "User Details",
        //                       content:"/Administration/EditUser",
        //                        actions: ["Close"],
        //                        modal: false,
        //                        resizable: false,
        //                        visible: false,
        //                        draggable: false,
        //                        animation: false,
        //                }).data("kendoWindow");


    });

    function AddRoletoUser(e) {
        if (e.item.textContent == "+") {

            var win = $("#RolesWindow").kendoWindow({
                width: "505px",
                height: "310px",
                title: "Add Roles to User",
                content: "/Administration/AddUserInRole",
                actions: ["Close"],
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                visible: false
            }).data("kendoWindow");

            win.center();
            win.open();

        }
        else if (e.item.textContent == "-") {
            var agree = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the Assigned Role ?");
            if (agree) {

                jsonData = "UserName=" + selectedUser + "&RoleName=" + selectedRole;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    url: 'http://' + servername + '/uBillingServices/Security/Security.svc/deleteRoleFromUser',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    async: false,
                    data: jsonData,
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                    }
                });


                Rolesgrid.getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();

            }
            else
                return false;
        }


    }
    function AddNewUser(e) {
        if (e.item.textContent == "+") {
            var win = $("#NewUserWindow").data("kendoWindow");
            win.refresh();
            win.center();
            win.open();

        }
        else if (e.item.textContent == "-") {
            var agree = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the User ?");
            if (agree) {
                jsonData = "UserName=" + selectedUser;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    url: 'http://' + servername + '/uBillingServices/Security/Security.svc/deleteUser',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    async: false,
                    data: jsonData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#grdUsers").getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        $("#grdUsers").getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
                    }
                });





            }
            else
                return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: As @mdcuesta said there is no official way of getting it in the client _but_ it is very likely that you can do it in the server. Since the data is provided by a server (not a local JSON), I do recommend to check [`serverSorting`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#serversorting-booleandefault)

Answer (score 2):

i see you are using kendo ui grid...

i'm not familiar with it by according to this link it is not possible to sort case insensitive

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/how-to-enable-case-insensitive-sorting-on-kendo-ui-grid.aspx

but there is a hack there to achieve case insensitive sorting: